# Select2 show more values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I created select2 drop-down. Now I want to add description, city, shop, etc. in this drop-down show by country name.
How can I add country city name, area, shop etc?

```
    (function($) {
        $(function() {
            var isoCountries = [
                { id: 'QA', text: 'Qatar',},
                { id: 'CA', text: 'Canada'},
                { id: 'CN', text: 'China'},
                { id: 'DE', text: 'Germany'},
                { id: 'RU', text: 'Russia'},
                { id: 'IT', text: 'Italy'}
            ];

            $("[name='market']").select2({
                placeholder: "Select a country",
                data: isoCountries
            });
        }); 
    })(jQuery);
```

[image]

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

use this option to edit the viewing html of select2:

`formatSelection: function(item) {
    return item.text + ' ' + item.xxx; // Some other property
}`

Comment: see the example page source (Ctrl+U) to see extra data is shown in html in select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code below:

```js
(function($) {
    var isoCountries = [
        { id: 'US', text: 'USA', description: 'New York'},
        { id: 'SP', text: 'Spain', description: 'Barcelona'}
    ];

    $("[name='market']").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a country",
        data: isoCountries,
        templateResult: function(data){
          return $('<span>')
            .html(data.text + ' - ')
            .append($('<i>')
            .html(data.description));
        },
        templateSelection: function(data){
          return $('<span>')
            .html(data.text + ' - ')
            .append($('<i>')
            .html(data.description));
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select name="market" style="width:100%;"></select>
```

**It works only for select2 version 4+.** If you want to use it with previous versions instead of usisng templateResult and templateSelection use formatResult and formatSelection.